# Can gufw profiles be switched automatically?

Tags: gufw

In **gufw**, you can set up different profiles (home, office, ...) with different rules.

This is cool, but: Is there a way to automatically select a profile, depending on the presence of a wifi access point for example ?

I couldn't find any information on that in the docs (in fact the possibility to have different profiles is barely mentioned, except for the screenshots...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't believe so, however it appears that NetworkManager supports Fedora's [FirewallD](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD), which allows configuration of a firewall zone for each network connection (such as Wifi SSIDs).  It is available in Ubuntu 15.10, but the graphical configuration utility, firewall-config, apparently is not, which means configuring it is left to the cli firewall-cmd application.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with `gufw`. `gufw` is a GUI for `ufw` (and `ufw` configures `iptables`). `ufw` doesn't know anything about the `gufw` profiles. You have to use `ufw` to enable/disable rules which are defined in your `gufw` profiles, E.g.

```
ufw allow in http 
ufw reject out smtp
```

For more examples and the usage of `ufw` use `man ufw` in your terminal.

---

Your next question on Ask Ubuntu should be: "How can I change my firewall settings in dependency of my network environment?"