# How can I change my firewall settings in dependency of my network environment?

Tags: networking, firewall, gufw

I need ports open at home for [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/), but want incoming connections blocked when on any other network. How do I do this with Ubuntu?

Without this feature I quite often end up turning off the laptop at home with the firewall off, then turning the laptop on at say work and having it connect automatically to a network where I wanted the firewall on, leaving a window of extra vulnerability while I get the firewall turned back on. Not ideal!

---

Prompted by: https://askubuntu.com/a/688912/79266

I'm currently using [gufw](http://gufw.org/). See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw

P.S. Windows can do this.

Comment: AN example: `sudo ufw allow from 15.15.15.0/24 to any port 873` or `$ sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.215 proto udp to any port 88` specifying a protocol

Comment: Use the needed port in place of mine

Comment: Home net is always wifi?

Comment: Neat, thanks @George, Though home is 192.* which sometimes matches other networks (on my todo list).

Comment: @2707974 mostly wifi, though I also have cabled network

Comment: Glade it worked out. include an answer please accept. :)

Comment: firewalld + https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/firewall-applet/ seems to be the answer I was after. https://askubuntu.com/a/406784/79266

Answer (score 0):

Solution would be:

1. Identify the network address for your home network or any other you want to associate a port with.
2. Tell `ufw` to allow traffic from that network via that port like so:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow from 15.15.15.0/24 to any port 873

   # another example

   sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.215 proto udp to any port 88
   ```

Note:

The ports chosen are purely imaginary pick that which fits your setup, same situation for network address.